# couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=SitemapCheck.SitemapAction,maxpri=10]

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have java maven project which is working fine in my computer but when i upload this project to the ubuntu server and trying to run it on command line using following command its give me error.

**Command line code:**

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=SitemapCheck.SitemapAction
```

**Its give me error Like**

```
[WARNING] NOTE: 2 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to  via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=SitemapCheck.SitemapAction,maxpri=10]
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.destroy(ThreadGroup.java:778)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:321)
        at
```

After search on the internet i found one solution but unfortunately its not working

```
 cleanupDaemonThreads = false
```

Can anyone please suggest me how can i fixed the error?

Comment: That is no error. It is a warning

Comment: please see the error after warning massage

Comment: Codes run but after gives few output its stopped..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was having the same thread warning issue with that `org.codehaus.mojo` package that also included a `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException` and this command worked for me:

`mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false`

Comment: Thank you for the pointer! My application was hanging after finishing, and it turns out that the Exec Maven Plugin was trying to shut down a daemon thread in the AWS Java SDK and it wasn't responding.

Answer (score 2):

To build further on the answer of [@Azurespot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070434/15792398), you can specify this parameter within the pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <exec.cleanupDaemonThreads>false</exec.cleanupDaemonThreads>
</properties>
```

from now on you can just launch it with:

```
mvn compile exec:java
```

Answer (score 0):

**The command that works along with the main class**

***Also works with mongoDB Learning Platform for the java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException Exception***

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.mdbu.app.DemoApp -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false
```