# Java - HttpClient not releasing threads

Tags: java, java-11, maven-exec-plugin

I am using Java 11's built in HTTP client and facing a strange issue with the client not releasing threads. I have the following code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.ALWAYS).build();
    HttpResponse<Void> response;

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(new URI("http://127.0.0.1:4321")).headers("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("{}")).build();

    response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());
}
```

and I am running the application with maven's exec plugin but getting the following errors:

```
[WARNING] thread Thread[HttpClient-1-Worker-0,5,com.example.httpclient.App] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 14995msecs
[WARNING] thread Thread[HttpClient-1-Worker-0,5,com.example.httpclient.App] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] thread Thread[HttpClient-1-Worker-1,5,com.example.httpclient.App] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] thread Thread[HttpClient-1-Worker-2,5,com.example.httpclient.App] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 3 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to  via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=com.example.httpclient.App,maxpri=10]
```

It seems the client is not releasing its threads properly. Interestingly if I comment out the code that sends the request (while keeping the code that creates the client) then the above warnings go away.

If I add `System.exit(0)` at the end then the warnings go away too but I am still wondering why this is happening with the built-in client? There is no close method on the client, request or the response so I don't think I am leaking resources.

I even set the client to null and called GC manually even then the problem persists. Very confused whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpClient` uses an internal thread pool with daemon threads. It seems the client doesn't explicitly shutdown this thread pool when it is garbage collected.

The warning you are seeing is related to the infrastructure put in place by your maven plugin. It seems others have experienced similar issues (see for instance [couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=SitemapCheck.SitemapAction,maxpri=10]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871635/couldnt-destroy-threadgroup-org-codehaus-mojo-exec-execjavamojoisolatedthreadg)).

A possible workaround to suppress the warning would be to supply an `Executor` to the `HttpClient.Builder`, and shutdown this `Executor` in your main method.

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Builder.html#executor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)

For the record, if no executor is supplied to the `HttpClient.Builder`, the `HttpClient` uses an executor as returned by [Executors.newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)).

Comment: you know why it needs an executor? It creates new threads even for synchronous requests.

Comment: In JDK 17 the behaviour was modified to shutdown the default executor when the client was garbage collected.
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8258582

Note that since JDK 21 HttpClient is AutoCloseable. It also offers shutdown/shutdownNow/awaitTermination methods.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#closing

Comment: :( why it needs an executor in the first place for the synchronous tasks?

Comment: Because it's fully asynchronous. The synchronous API just waits for the asynchronous task to complete.

Comment: understood. but it does not make sense. It seems to use cached thread pool to create threads unnecessarily for the synchronous tasks. Ideally it should use calling thread synchronous tasks.

Comment: That's what the first prototype was doing. But it meant there was two separate implementations to maintain and test, and you had to factor in protocol versions and clear vs TLS and proxy vs no proxy on top of it, and that really didn't make sense. Plus the API is really asynchronous (using Flow and Reactive Stream) - which made it doubly more complex to maintain the two code paths.

An HttpClient is not made to send a single request and close, like the old HttpURLConnection was. You can use it that way, but it's a waste of resources.